# Netbeans FTP - Remote Server Project refuses to sync

Tags: netbeans

I have a project uploaded at an offsite FTP server which I work on in the Netbeans IDE,  the uploading and downloading of the project files works fine and functions correctly, but when making changes to a file and then synchronising, the IDE refuses to upload **some** (not random, the same files every time) files to the FTP server with error message `Could not change to directory /project/`.

I wish I could share more specific information, but this is all I am working with myself. It's odd because it synchronises other files in the same location (/projects/*) just fine.

Comment: I've experienced something very similar - I eventually gave up on it. Not sure if it's a netbeans bug or not.

Comment: Check the file permissions?